# How to get Oracle SQL query to sort by column name

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I write an SQL query such that the columns are alphabetically ordered from left to right?

If I were to use `select alpha, bravo, charlie, delta from ..` then the column names would be sorted from left to right because I explicitly put them in order.  How can I do this without explicitly writing out all of the column names?

Comment: You cant unless you use some dynamic sql to build your query as a string and then execute it. The big question is why and will it be worth the effort.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Columns do not have any order. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You type the columns into the query in the order you want them.

Comment: Is there a real purpose of selecting the columns in an order

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view with the help of this SQL in your schema and then select from that view

```
SELECT 'create or replace view tasks_alp as select ' 
       || Listagg(column_name, ',') 
            within GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) 
       ||' from tasks' 
FROM   user_tab_cols 
WHERE  table_name = 'TASKS' 
       AND column_name NOT LIKE 'SYS%$';
```

The Sample output is

```
    create or replace view tasks_alp as select ID,SEQ,STATE from tasks
```

Then you can select the columns using

```
 select * from tasks_alp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- FOR MS SQL    

select c.name from sys.tables t
inner join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id
where t.name = 'TableName'
order by c.name
```

Comment: Given that the question is _explicitly_ about Oracle, it seems like an odd choice to answer for Microsoft SQL.

Comment: I searched for an SQL version but couldn't find one on this site, so thought I'd post the code to do it.  I can delete if you want.